# get course between two point in google maps

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have two point in **Google Maps**

```
pointA = -6.468151012664202, 106.77200317382812
pointB = -6.121438675500974, 106.47125244140625
```

How can I get the course/bearing using **JavaScript** or **MySQL Query**?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While it's a wealth of information, it is not a code writing service. There's an awful amount of resources available for the Google Maps API. Have a go, see how far you get, and then if you're stuck come back with some code and people will help. Please look [here to see how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then [here to learn how to provide a complete, minimal and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use the Google Maps API's `geometry` library.  When you load in the JS, you need to add the `libraries=geometry` URL parameter to the JS script.

Then, you can do:

```
var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(-6.468151012664202, 106.77200317382812);
var pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(-6.121438675500974, 106.47125244140625);

var bearing = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(pointA, pointB);
```

See:
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical

Comment: how to use it nodejs(backend) ?